# ViewPagerAdapter "id cannot be resolved or is not a field "

Tags: java, android, layout, import

I have the following code in eclipse and i can't put the correct layout and imageview because cannot be resolved or are not a field

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] gallery) {
    this.context = context;
    this.gallery = gallery;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gallery.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);
    // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
    ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Picasso.with(context).load(gallery[position]).into(imgflag);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}
```

I tried cleanning the project importing R, and making rigth click in my project/"Android tools"/"Fix project properties".
I have this problem only when i create an adapter class

Comment: Include your layout file contents above.  Most likely you have a mistake in the XML which is causing the R file to not get generated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use group of key `Ctr + Shift + o` to let eclipse auto import neccessary things for your project.